# how to solve such UMP where utility function is quasi-linear with cobb-douglas function as the non-linear part

Tags: utility, cobb-douglas

[image]

U =$X_1+X_2^aX_3^{1-a}$  $a ∈[0,1]$

$s.t.  p·x≤w  ,  x≥0 $

I have tried FOC for x1 x2 x3 and λ, but I cannot get two pairs of equalities separately in order to express two unknowns as a function of the
third from the FOC. (for example, express x1 with x2 and x3) So I cannot substitute the solutions into the budget constraint so that we only have one unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Try cases:

1. $x_2 = 0$ or $x_3 = 0$, then consume $x_1$ only.
2. If only $x_1 = 0$, solve for the Walrasian for Cobb Douglas
3. All $x$ are non-zeros. I have a feeling you might reach a contradiction in the Kuhn-Tucker conditions, so you will be able to rule out this case.

Anyhow, you need to work this out on your own.

Comment: This is incorrect, there are solutions where all x are non-zero. They occur when $p_1 = \min_{x_2,x_3}\{p_2x_2 + p_3x_3 \lvert x_2^\alpha x_3^{1-\alpha} \geq 1 \}$.